# Which structure is better? - PHP HTTP library

Tags: php, http, structure

Which structure will be useful/better?
(PHP)

**Structure A**

```
+ httpLib/
|   . Index.php / Factory
|   . API.php
|   . _Exception.php
|   + Response/
|   |   . Interface.php
|   |   . ...
|   + Request/
|   |   . Interface.php
|   |   . ...
```

**Structure B**

```
+ httpLib/
|   . Response.php
|   . Request.php
|   . API.php
|   . _Exception.php
|   + Client/
|   |   . Interface.php
|   |   . Socket.php
|   |   . Stream.php
|   |   . cURL.php
...
```

*(I did not find a better title)*
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first structure is the best.

With it you can better separate the requests and responses.

The structures of the requests and responses are well defined and not in a single class

Comment: for requests(curl, socket, stream...) is ok, but what kind of responses?

Comment: The HTTP Responses: 1xx: Informational - Request received, continuing process. 2xx: Success - The action was successfully received, understood, and accepted. 3xx: Redirection - Further action must be taken in order to complete the request. 4xx: Client Error - The request contains bad syntax or cannot be fulfilled. 5xx: Server Error - The server failed to fulfill an apparently valid request.